# "My mom once knew a guy who could do that" said Peter to Eric. Do they have any relation?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In X-Men Days of Future Past, when Peter saved Eric from prison, in the scene where they were both in elevator, Peter said to Eric:

> "They told me you control metal, you know, my mom once knew a guy who could do that",

What is behind this? Do they have any relation or something?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The character of Peter Maximoff / Quicksilver is an adaptation of Comic book character Pietro Maximoff. From the Marvel comics storyline, **Quicksilver is the son of Magneto (Eric Lehnserr) and Magda**. He is the **twin brother of Scarlett Witch**.

There are lot of differences between the Marvel comics X-Men storyline and the X-Men movies.

In the book, X-Factor Annual #4 Magneto and Magda escape from concentration camp and got married and settled down (as per the comic book storyline Magneto's name was Max and he changed it later to Eric). After marriage when Magda saw the powers of Magneto she fled out of fear and gave birth to twins Pietro and Wanda. Both were raised as Quicksilver and Scarlett Witch.

P.s. during the movie scene where Magneto attacks the White House and starts the Live TV coverage, Peter (or Pietro a.k.a Quicksilver) is shown watching it on TV with his sister who has red hair, it **MIGHT** be reference to Wanda (i.e. Scarlett Witch), his mutant sister.

Comment: But she was too younger for being Wanda.

Comment: [“Is that the Scarlet Witch? No, that’s his little sister,” Singer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/who-is-that-girl-in-x-men-days-of-future-past)

Comment: thats why I said, might be... and there are bazillion differences between the comic canon and movie... they try to copy some context from comics and keep some suspense / doubt, either mistakenly or intentionally...

Comment: There's also a difference between "who she is" and "who she's referencing."  They can make an easter-egg out of a little sister with red hair, without her ACTUALLY being Scarlett Witch.  I definitely picked up on that being a reference to Wanda.

Comment: you are right @Nerrolken, it can be a reference to Wanda. Then again its just a speculation. Lets see what they show in the next X-men movie with Apocalypse in it...

Comment: Not only difference between comics and X-Men movies, but potentially between comics and X-Men movies and Marvel Cinematic Universe (i.e. Avengers). Interested to see how that might sort out. Sony is crossing over, maybe Fox will cross mutants and MCU as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the final trailer for *X-Men: Apocalypse*, Pietro specifically tells Mystique that Magneto is his father.

> Magneto... is my father

He then begins to try to explain how that worked.